# JSON parsing in python gives error

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a json file which looks something like below:

```
{ "results": [ 
{ "ID": "63768E9B-1D66-486A-BCDD-D3991EAFBE94", 
"Dt": "2013-08-03T13:01:26.901Z", 
"Dt_u": "2013-08-03T13:01:26.901Z", 
"obj": "enppXhI7TS" 
}, 
{ 
"ID": "63768E9B-1D66-486A-BCDD-D3991EAFBE94", 
"Dt": "2013-08-03T16:17:33.280Z",
"Dt_u": "2013-08-03T16:17:33.280Z",
"obj": "79J5z6y2UR" 
}, 
{ 
"ID": "F8B1B9FB-7BCD-47DF-89BD-241440BB6270",
"Dt": "2013-08-06T00:23:43.562Z", 
"obj": "Xf75BFtx4O",
"gender": 2,
"language": "en"
}]}
```

There are many more entries in the file

Now when i try to load this file using JSON Parser in python, it gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = json.dumps(json_data)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "C:\python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "C:\python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "C:\python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <open file 'data.json', mode 'r' at 0x00000000022E6540> is not JSON  
serializable
```

[Finished in 0.9s with exit code 1]

My code is

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


json_data=open('data.json','r')

data = json.dumps(json_data)
jsondata = data["results"]

for item in jsondata:
name = item.get("ID")
json_data.close()
```

<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


json_data=open('data.json','r')

data = json.load(json_data)
jsondata = data["results"]

for item in jsondata:
name = item.get("ID")
json_data.close()
```

Error that it gives now -->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_data)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
   obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2: invalid    continuation byte
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I know it is related to some Unicode data. but how do i identify and resolve it?

Comment: What JSON parser are you talking about?

Comment: You missed the comma after "obj": "Xf75BFtx4O", is that copy-paste error?

Comment: @msvalkon - Updated with code.

Comment: @user3 - Yes. Updated accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to dump a string that is a file that you are reading from. If that sentence doesn't make sense to you that's because the underlying operation is nonsensical. Try `json.load()` instead.

Comment: I tried that. But now it is giving me UnicodeDecodeError. Details updated in question

Comment: If you have a new question then open a new question.

Comment: Posted a new question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823792/json-parsing-in-python-gives-error-unicodedecodeerror

Answer (score 0):

Firstly here is syntax error in the data your pasted. Missing one comma in the end of line 17.

Secondly you need to call json.load(json_data) in order to load json from file.

Answer (score 0):

First,there are no keys named *seniorID*,second you need use `json.load(json_data)`

Comment: Updated key and json.load