# JSON parsing in python gives error - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, json

My JSON file is

```
{ "results": [ 
{ "ID": "63768E9B-1D66-486A-BCDD-D3991EAFBE94", 
"Dt": "2013-08-03T13:01:26.901Z", 
"Dt_u": "2013-08-03T13:01:26.901Z", 
"obj": "enppXhI7TS" 
}, 
{ 
"ID": "63768E9B-1D66-486A-BCDD-D3991EAFBE94", 
"Dt": "2013-08-03T16:17:33.280Z",
"Dt_u": "2013-08-03T16:17:33.280Z",
"obj": "79J5z6y2UR" 
}, 
{ 
"ID": "F8B1B9FB-7BCD-47DF-89BD-241440BB6270",
"Dt": "2013-08-06T00:23:43.562Z", 
"obj": "Xf75BFtx4O",
"gender": 2,
"language": "en"
}]}
```

There are many more entries in the file

My python code is as follows

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


json_data=open('data.json','r')

data = json.load(json_data)
jsondata = data["results"]

for item in jsondata:
name = item.get("ID")
json_data.close()
```

When i try to run the file, it gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = json.load(json_data)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
   obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 2: invalid    continuation byte
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Can somebody help me and tell how do i resolve it?

Comment: This is an decoding problem. Do you know if the encoding of the file is UTF-8? If not try UTF-16 perhaps: `io.open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-16')`. I can't say for sure of course without having access to the file.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7. So i think encoding argument is not supported there

Comment: Import the `io` module and use `io.open` if you need to specify the encoding. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html (Supported since 2.6 I believe.)

Comment: Done. It is giving me this error 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 298662-298663: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Comment: Looks like it's not UTF-16 either. Do you know the encoding of the file? Where did you get it from? Can you inspect it to find out its encoding?

Comment: I got it from internet. So i am not sure about its encoding. Regarding finding its encoding, let me try it out

Comment: The place where you downloaded it from *should* mention the encoding, especially if it is different from utf-8 or utf-16 which are two most common encodings. Inspecting the content of the file might give you some clues, but at the end of the day, it is the source's responsibility to clearly indicate the file's encoding.

Comment: Ok. Encoding is 'windows-1252'. And file worked fine. Thanks for your answer. You can write it as answer. Will accept it

Comment: This is great software to find encoding
http://encodingchecker.codeplex.com/